# Basic if/then JS/JQuery - Why does this appear to ignore the IF and execute twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I've tried about 2 dozen different variations of this and all roads lead to a result that looks like the IF is being completely ignored. Thoughts?

```
function checkthebox(name,val){
    alert(name + val)
    if(val === 'no');{ 
        alert('The value is ' + val +' for ' + name);
        $('input[name='+name+']').attr('checked', false).button("refresh"); 
    }
    if(val === 'yes');{ alert('The value is ' + val +' for ' + name);
        $('input[name='+name+']').attr('checked', true).button("refresh"); 
    }
}
checkthebox('epcf11','yes');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 if(val === 'no');{
```

should be

```
 if(val === 'no') {
```

Comment: Thank you guys! - I was convinced I had a ' where I needed a " or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolons before the {

Semicolons mark the end of an instruction, your brackets then just create a new block.

Your if should look like:

```
if (val==='yes'){
```

Answer (score -1):

I seen the extra semi's too, I went and tested it out, the conditionals still work even with the ';'
http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/